# Is it possible to loop all the result of a select statement in a where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a 10k rows db, each one rappresenting a contract with a name on it, there are different contract with the same name and I would like to add a column with the same number for the same name.
To select all the names I implemented this:

```
SELECT cliente FROM tbl_c WHERE id IN 
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_c GROUP BY name)
```

Now I would like to loop in something like this

```
SET @num:=10000
FOR EACH Element IN *Selection Above*
UPDATE tbl_c
SET num_column=@num WHERE name=Element
@num:=@num+1
```

Is it possible to do something like this with mysql?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one query with a self-join:

```
UPDATE tbl_c AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM tbl_c
    GROUP BY name
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @num := 999) AS vars
SET num_column = (@num := @num + 1)
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't do the things I want: I would like to give all the column with the same name the same number

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0. You could use the `RANK()` window function for that.

Comment: See the linked question, it has answers showing how to calculate dense rank in MySQL. Join with a subquery that does that, and then assign the appropriate rank.